# Magento2 - Getting wrong From email Address in Back in Stock email

Tags: magento2

I have a multi-store setup, I am facing issue when Product back in stock emails are getting fired. I am getting emails of Back in stock but the 'Form' email Address is taken from default store & not a specific store.

I am fetching email address from 'Sales Representative' in Admin under Store Email Address.